# I can not open webpage with url directly in ReactJS homepage deployed by Github

Tags: reactjs, github

I build website with ReactJS and `App.js` has below Routers.

```
<Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path="/"
      element={<SignIn changeLoggedInState={changeLoggedInState} />}
    />
    <Route
      path="/summary"
      element={loggedIn ? <Summary /> : <NotLoggedIn />}
    />
    <Route path="/users" element={loggedIn ? <Users /> : <NotLoggedIn />} />
    <Route path="/ranks" element={loggedIn ? <Ranks /> : <NotLoggedIn />} />
    <Route
      path="/service"
      element={loggedIn ? <Service /> : <NotLoggedIn />}
    />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

And This works really well.

I deployed this webpage with `Github`.

And also it works perfect.

But when I type address directly by `url` address, web page is not opened.

404 page opens.

-> https://hayatshin.github.io/todaychungchun-admin/summary

But if I access this address not by typing directly but by clicking button and navigate based on code it works.

When I didn't deploy it and worked on `localhost`, I could access page by url.

It happens only after deployment and with deployed webpage.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This may be a problem with your github configuration?

Comment: @devpolo which part should I change configuration in github?